# Different result of date format in output file

Tags: python, linux, bash, scripting, ssconvert

I am creating .txt file from .xlsx file using `ssconvert` command. But issue is not being able to maintain data format in output .txt file -  is appearing something else.

Please help me to fix the `ssconvert` command so that I can get the same date (20-Jun-2018) format in .txt as present in .xlsx file.

Command used :

```
ssconvert -O 'separator="^" format=raw' Prepay_TRAI_Format_Universal_22Jun.xlsx Prepay_TRAI_Format_Universal_22Junwithc.txt
```

Input file:

```
Praid SV    test_Ud calls   TT0088  Ta  Guj     GS  Prepaid Launch      test8       22-Jun-2018 20-Jun-2018 Regular
```

Output of `ssconvert` command:

```
"Praid SV"^"test_Ud calls"^TT0088^"Ta"^Guj^^GS^Prepaid^Launch^^tes8^^43273^43271^Regular
```

Comment: Done..fixed the command using , preserved keyword instead of raw

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.